# How to create and parse string enums with values in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I know that there is issue with creating string enums using Typescript, even in v2.4+
I'm using typescript 2.8 and Angular 6.

I would like to have an enum and to freely get string value from enum, and to parse string into enum.

So assume I have this enum:

```
export enum MyEnum{
  INIT = 'init-room',
  CLOSE = 'close-room'
}
```

This enum is useful to communicate with rest API. So from API and to API I have to send strings. But inside app I want to asap convert string from API to enum.

So I want to have function to parse, and stringify my enum.

I try this approach, but this won't work.

```
export function toString(type: MyEnum): string {
    return MyEnum[type];
}

export function parse(type: string): Mode {
    return MyEnum[type];
}
```

Well, it isn't big surprise, because I want to get `value` from this enum, not `MyEnum[type]` - but I don't know how to do this.

I know that there is an issue with converting key to value, while value to key works.
So I'm asking for any clean-code solution to achieve my goal.

Comment: I'm confused by your terminology and lack of concrete examples.  It's easy to turn a key of an enum into a value given the enum object.  A string enum does not store the reverse mapping from value back to key, but you can probably write code to do it.  Or are you trying to cast a string to an enum value?  Maybe edit your question with some code you'd like to see work.  That is: suppose that the functions you wanted actually existed; how exactly would you use them?   Then someone could maybe show how to write those functions or tell you why it isn't possible.

Comment: I think the OP is using a RESTful interface and receiving a string key that he would like to convert it to an enum (i.e. MyEnum).  So for example, on the receiving side of the REST call he might get the string "INIT" which should be converted to MyEnum.INIT.  So, if I'm correct in my assumption, it is fair to ask this question as I would like to know as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to get value like this:

```
return MyEnum.type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
enumValues(enumType:any):number[] {
    return Object.keys(enumType).map(k => enumType[k]).filter(v => typeof v === "number")
}

enumString(enumType:any, enumValue:any):string {
    return enumType[enumValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can safely switch to constant instead.